# Is there a python function to generate the byte code for python code strings?

Tags: python, bytecode, built-in, bytecode-manipulation

for example can I do something like this

```
pythonCode = "print 'hello world'"
pyc = generate_bytecode(pythonCode)
```

where pyc would contain the bytecode for pythonCode?

**Edit:** My goal is essentially to get exactly what would would be written to a .pyc in file into a variable. magic number, timestamp, hex version of code and all

Comment: Can I ask what is your use-case?

Comment: I noticed while messing with a pyc file that spaces in python 2.7.5 bytecode don't matter and that you can directly call python on .pyc files. I want to write an obfuscator for python code that uses the generated bytecode

Comment: Not for security reasons, just because I'm bored and this sounds like something fun to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`compiler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html) package:

> > The [`compiler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/compiler.html#module-compiler) package is a Python source to bytecode translator written in Python. It uses the built-in parser and standard [`parser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html#module-parser) module to generate a concrete syntax tree. This tree is used to generate an abstract syntax tree (AST) and then Python bytecode.

Comment: I've resolved to just using the compileFile method from the compiler package to generate the pyc file and read it back into memory as opposed to using the actual compile.compile command as it was much more difficult to figure out how to get the fully generated pyc file using the latter method. Because this answer just generally recommends the compiler package, this will be my accepted answer. Thank you to all that answered however. All comments and reponses were helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Passing `'exec'` as the `mode` to [`compile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile) will generate a code object from Python statements. Accessing the `co_code` attribute of the code object will give you the raw bytecode. Note that this alone will be mostly useless without the other `co_*` attributes though.

```
>>> c = compile('print a', '<string>', 'exec')
>>> dir(c)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'co_argcount', 'co_cellvars', 'co_code', 'co_consts', 'co_filename', 'co_firstlineno', 'co_flags', 'co_freevars', 'co_lnotab', 'co_name', 'co_names', 'co_nlocals', 'co_stacksize', 'co_varnames']
>>> c.co_code
'e\x00\x00GHd\x00\x00S'
>>> c.co_names
('a',)
>>> c.co_consts
(None,)
>>> dis.dis(c)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: dont get the dis.dis(c) bit

Comment: import dis , https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html

Answer (score 2):

It's called [`compile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile):

```
>>> compile('print "Hi!"', 'abc', 'single')
<code object <module> at 0000000002555D30, file "abc", line 1>
>>> eval(compile('print "Hi!"', 'abc', 'single'))
Hi!
```